# Shouldn't responses count get reset if I already viewed it throught inbox notifications?

Tags: support, feature-request, user-interface

This question is about the user interface. I always use the icon in the top bar to see all notifications, but, if I visit the `Activity` tab in my profile, I still see that the `responses` has a count. The same apply for the `reputation` count and the `achievements` icon in the top bar.

It is showing me a notification for a content that I already viewed, is this a bug in the interface? Or are different concepts behind every element?

Wouldn't be nice that if I already view the content of a notification no matter if we use the top bar icon or the tab in the user profile interface, all notifications count get reset?
[image]

Comment: Global inbox !== specific site responses

Comment: I find it useful to separate the real time count, which I clear pretty often, from a count that I can review when I occasionally go to my profile.

Comment: @Braiam i know that, but the content is the same, we get an inbox notification of a comment, then we go and read it, then, why `responses` still show me that we have 1 notification of a comment we already read? Make sense?